# Yapsy instantiates the wrong class when IPlugin is extended

Tags: python, plugins

I have the following file structure, which implements a very simple plugin architecture using [Yapsy](http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/index.html).

#### Plugins/BasePlugin.py

```
from yapsy.IPlugin import IPlugin

class BasePlugin(IPlugin):
    def process(self):
        # Do some stuff common to all plugins
        pass
```

#### Plugins/TestPlugin.py

```
from Plugins.BasePlugin import BasePlugin

class TestPlugin(BasePlugin):
    def process(self, info):
        super(TestPlugin, self).process()
        # Do stuff
        return "done"
```

#### test.py

```
from yapsy.PluginManager import PluginManager
from Plugins.BasePlugin import BasePlugin
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
# See note 1
manager = PluginManager()   # Does not work
manager = PluginManager(categories_filter={'BasePlugin': BasePlugin}) # Works

def init_plugins():
    # Load the plugins from the plugin directory.
    manager.setPluginPlaces(["Plugins"])
    manager.collectPlugins()

    # Loop round the plugins and print their names.
    for plugin in manager.getAllPlugins():
        manager.activatePluginByName(plugin.name, "BasePlugin")
        print "Plugin path: {}".format(plugin.path)
        print "Plugin obj:  {}".format(plugin.plugin_object)

        result = plugin.plugin_object.process(info)
```

There is also the correct .yapsy-plugin information file for TestPlugin.

Without the filter (at note 1) Yapsy tries to instantiate a BasePlugin instead of my TestPlugin, despite the plugin's name being "TestPlugin".  For example:

```
Plugin path: /home/user/python/Plugins/TestPlugin
Plugin obj:  <Plugins.BasePlugin.BasePlugin object at 0x7f159af22050>
```

If I include the filter then plugins are loaded correctly and my TestPlugin class is instantiated and used instead.

```
DEBUG:yapsy:Activating plugin: BasePlugin.test
Plugin path: /home/david/python/Plugins/TestPlugin
Plugin obj:  <yapsy_loaded_plugin_test_0.TestPlugin object at 0x7f4dad7d4050>
```

Am I doing something wrong with inheritance, or is this just how Yapsy works?  I can't see why it would try to use BasePlugin instead of TestPlugin despite finding the correct file.

Do I need to implement categories to extend [IPlugin](http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/IPlugin.html) and provide my own base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've come across a known problem of yapsy which is related to the way it detects plugins in files and categorizes them.

This is explained in the troubleshooting section of yapsy's doc at https://yapsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Advices.html#plugin-class-detection-caveat.

Since these are already my own words, I'll just copy-paste them here, but if something's unclear, feel free to ask for precisions.

---

There must be only one plugin defined per module. This means that you can’t have two plugin description files pointing at the same module for instance.

Because of the “categorization by inheritance” system, you mustn’t directly import the subclass of `IPlugin` in the main plugin file, instead import its containing module and make your plugin class inherit from `ContainingModule.SpecificPluginClass` as in the following example.

The following code won’t work (the class `MyBasePluginClass` will be detected as the plugin’s implementation instead of `MyPlugin`):

```
from myapp.plugintypes import MyBasePluginClass

class MyPlugin(MyBasePluginClass):
    pass
```

Instead you should do the following:

```
import myapp.plugintypes as plugintypes

class MyPlugin(plugintypes.MyBasePluginClass):
    pass
```